# how to update a column in a mysql table using sqlachemy?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, sql-update, flask-sqlalchemy

Here are all the different things I tried:

## 1

```
query = db.session.query(Table1)
query = query.filter(Table1.id == '12345')
record = query.one()
record.trackingId = 'UPSTXNID1'
db.session.flush()
```

## 2

```
sqlalchemy.update(Table1)\
    .values({Table1.trackingId: 'UPSTXNID1'})\
    .where(Table1.id == '12345)
```

## 3

```
session.query(Table1)\
        .filter(Table1.id == '12345')\
        .update({Table1.trackingId: 'UPSTXNID1'})
session.commit()
```

## 4

```
db.engine.execute(
   "UPDATE Table1 SET trackingId=:trackingId WHERE id=:id",
   {'id': '12345', 'trackingId': 'UPSTXNID1'}
)
```

All of them don't throw any error, but trackingId column doesn't get updated with value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small variation of 2nd one worked after I called execute.

```
stmt = sqlalchemy.update(Table1).\
            values(trackingId = 'UPSTXNID1').\
            where(Table1.id == '12345')
db.engine.execute(stmt)

# If you want to see the underlying SQL statement that is created
print str(stmt.compile(dialect=sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dialect()))
```